# MPAndroidChart - Show MarkerView on long click

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I have **CustomMarkerView** with `PieChart` on [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), however I want to show the marker only when the chart is longClicked.

Is there any way I can achieve this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. I rebuilded this project from [github](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/144). The first hint was from this [post](https://programmersought.com/article/91423908698/). You inherit your `PieChart` or every chart you want and apply a `onTouchEvent` on it. You create a class called `ChartMarkerView` and extends it's `MarkerView`. There you bind a view and set the duration of the `ClickTime`.

Hope it will help you to approach your target!

**Update:**

In addition to the part above @AinulBedjo found out that you can reach the long click with `@Override` the `draw` method then only `draw` when the `longClicked` is `true`:

```
public class CustomPieChart extends PieChart {
    public CustomPieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            CustomMarker markerView = (CustomMarker) getMarker();
            isLongClicked = true;

            //get angle and index of dataset
            float angle = getAngleForPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
            int indexForAngle = getIndexForAngle(angle);

            // takes index of angle, Y-Position and dataSetIndex of 0
            Highlight highlight = new Highlight(indexForAngle, e.getY(), 0);
            highlightValue(highlight);

            // redraw
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            isLongClicked = false;
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
        }
    });

    Boolean isLongClicked = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean handled = true;
        // if there is no marker view or drawing marker is disabled
        if (isShowingMarker() && this.getMarker() instanceof CustomMarker){
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        handled = super.onTouchEvent(event);
        return handled;
    }

    // draw markers on highlighter values
    @Override
    protected void drawMarkers(Canvas canvas) {
        // if there is no marker view or drawing marker is disabled
        if (mMarker == null || !isDrawMarkersEnabled() || !valuesToHighlight())
            return;

        for (Highlight highlight : mIndicesToHighlight) {

            IDataSet set = mData.getDataSetByIndex(highlight.getDataSetIndex());

            Entry e = mData.getEntryForHighlight(highlight);
            int entryIndex = set.getEntryIndex(e);

            // make sure entry not null
            if (e == null || entryIndex > set.getEntryCount() * mAnimator.getPhaseX())
                continue;

            float[] pos = getMarkerPosition(highlight);

            // check bounds
            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBounds(pos[0], pos[1]))
                continue;

            // callbacks to update the content
            mMarker.refreshContent(e, highlight);

            // draw the marker
            if (isLongClicked) {
                mMarker.draw(canvas, pos[0], pos[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isShowingMarker(){
        return mMarker != null && isDrawMarkersEnabled();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it was removed. So it doesn't help you. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: No no no, It's a help for me. Tho I still can't figure it out to work like I want

Comment: I able to resolve my issue with the hint u gave me. But also with a little modification myself, Thanks

Comment: Could you paste a link with your solution to complete my answer. SO should work as an encyclopedia. Thus we have a good question matched with a complete answer. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ai-null/f1bce9d826776ec4554029c1843edc67

sure, there u go

Comment: the point is to override the draw method then only **draw** when the longClicked is true

Comment: Thanks for sharing I updated my answer to share it with everyone who is facing this problem. Nice collaboration and teamwork! Feel free to tick it as correct to highlight the answer. Cheers and Happy Coding! :)